# How to set output directory for the created zip archive using PHP ZipArchive class?

Tags: php, zip, php-ziparchive

I am using PHP `ZipArchive` class to archive files from different locations. Code is below

**php**

```
$files = array('path/1/file1.zip', 'path/2/file2.zip');
$zipname = "path/to/output/archive-" . time() . ".zip"; // Zip name

$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach ($files as $file) {
    
    $data = file_get_contents($file);
    
    $name =  basename($file, '.zip') . '.zip';
    if (file_exists($path)) {
        $zip->addFromString($name,  $data);
        
    } else {
        echo "file does not exist";
        exit;
    }
}
$zip->close();
```

Problem is it creates a zip file with name `path_to_output_archive-16783322.zip` file in root directory. I was expecting it to create `archive-16783322.zip` inside `path/to/output/` folder.

Comment: try `$zipname = __DIR__ . "/path/to/output/archive-" . time() . ".zip"`;

Comment: what's your PHP version? and where does `$path` point to? I tried your code snippet and it creates the destination file correctly, without using `__DIR__` as prefix.

Comment: `path/to/output` is a relative path, you can't tell where it starts unless you know the working directory of the PHP process. But that's typically the location of the main file.

Comment: Thank you it worked. The problem was I was also downloading the file and it was causing the issue. I have resolved it. Please post as answer I will mark it accepted

Comment: If the problem was somewhere else, and not in the zip creation code you've shared, you can just close the question.